# Azure CLI - Delete files in storage account with pattern

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cli

I have the following files and directories in my container.

[image: storage account]

I need to delete all files and directories except the mf folder and its content.
I use this command:

```
az storage blob delete-batch --source 'CONTAINER' --account-name STORAGE_ACCOUNT --pattern '[!mf]*'
```

The problem that this command not only avoids deleting the mf directory but also the files that start with the letter m and f

Is there a way to modify the pattern to include files starting with m and f?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To continue using az cli commands, I used the following command

```
blob=$(az storage blob list -c '$web' --account-name "$SA_NAME" --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv)
prefix="mf"

for b in $blob
do
  if [[ "$b" != "$prefix"* ]];
  then
    az storage blob delete -c '$web' --account-name "$SA_NAME" -n "$b"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to delete all files and directories except the mf folder and its content.

You can use the **Powershell** as an alternative way to achieve delete all files and directories except the mf folder and its content.

**Command:**

```
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'venkat123' -StorageAccountKey 'your-storage-account-key'
$containerName = "test"
$prefix = ""
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $containerName -Context $ctx -Prefix $prefix
foreach ($blob in $blobs) {
    if ($blob.Name -notlike "mf/*") {
        Remove-AzStorageBlob -Blob $blob.Name -Container $containerName -Context $ctx
    }
}
```

Initially, I had a structure of files.

[image]

When I use the above command it deletes all files and folders except the mf folder.

**Output:**
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use this command for deleting files inside the container.

az storage blob delete-batch --account-key <storage_account_key> --account-name <storage_account_name> --source <container_name> --delete-snapshots include